# How to include JS from node_modules in Vite in production?

Tags: javascript, import, vite, svelte

I have a svelte project that uses Vite for its build tooling. I want to import a js file from the [sakura-js package](https://github.com/jhammann/sakura) and call it in my index.html file. It works locally when I use the script tag like this:

```
    <script src="/node_modules/sakura-js/dist/sakura.min.js"></script>
```

But in prod, it gives a 404 error trying the script. How do I import the script so it works in prod?

Comment: Code in node_modules is not available to browsers unless Vite bundles it, but it is not like what you seem to be expecting.  I searched npmjs for the sakura package and only found one from 10 years ago.  I suppose it is not it.  Generally speaking, if you want to reference a package that can be run by the browser, you would use a CDN like jsdelivr.  By referencing the package from the CDN, there's no need for Vite to know about it.

Comment: @JoséRamírez I was able to get use the styles sheets and scripts in the dist folder of the sakura-js package by using jsdelivr like so in the index.html file:     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sakura-js/dist/sakura.min.css">
 and     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sakura-js/dist/sakura.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JavaScript file from the sakura-js package in production.

In your main script file (e.g., main.js or App.svelte), you can import the library like so:

```
import 'sakura-js/dist/sakura.min.js';

<script src="/sakura.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The extra script should be redundant.

Comment: Okay, so if I'm importing the script in my main.js or app file, then where do I call the function that instantiates the Sakura object? For what I'm referring to, see the setup instructions on the sakura docs https://github.com/jhammann/sakura

Answer (score 0):

import 'sakura-js/dist/sakura.min.js';

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Assuming Sakura is accessible globally and an element with id 'sakura-area' exists
    new window.Sakura('#sakura-area');
});

<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import 'sakura-js/dist/sakura.min.js';

  onMount(() => {
    // Ensure Sakura is available globally, then instantiate it targeting a specific element
    new window.Sakura('#sakura-area');
  });
</script>

<div id="sakura-area">
  <!-- The area where the Sakura effect will be applied -->
</div>
```

Comment: Which file(s) should I add this code to?

Comment: It depends on the structure and setup of your application, it could be main.js, app.js or App.svelte.

Comment: I couldnt get this to work in neither my App.svelte file nor my main.js file